# Reading in serialised objects from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, object, io, serializable

First time trying to read in objects from a file, how would I read in the file that I have written?

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4654676943759320425L;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> world;
private ArrayList<AFood> foods;
private ArrayList<ABlock> blocks;
private ArrayList<ABug> bugs;
private String name = null;
private int lengthX = 0, lengthY = 0;
```

This is the objects class (Just the variables)

```
open = new FileInputStream(worldSavedAs);
openBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(open);
openIn = new ObjectInputStream(openBuffer);
this.world = openIn.readObject();
```

This is how I am trying to read in the object currently

```
save = new FileOutputStream(worldNameAs + ".aBugsWorld");
saveBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(save);
saveOut = new ObjectOutputStream(saveBuffer);
saveOut.writeObject(this.worldSave); // Here was the problem
```

This is how I wrote the file

Obviously this is not correct and I have no idea how to read in objects, whether I have to insert the variables one by one or as a whole class I don't know.

EDIT: I was writing the stream to a file rather than my object which caused the problem (As File IO stream could not be cast to AWorld)

Comment: I was writing a File IO object to the file instead of my world! Silly me, sometimes it's the smallest things. Though now when I try to save the world, all the variables it tries to write it comes up with exception saying 'at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)'

Comment: ...and I had to serializable every other class that is used in the world.

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct. 
But one think , class which is going to be written on the file must be serializable.

You can also do like this :

1.> Class to be Written on file :

```
 class StudentRecord implements Serializable{
        String name;
        public StudentRecord(String name) {
            this.name=name;
        }  
    }
```

2.> Writing on to file

```
            File f=new File("xyz.txt");
            f.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutput oo=new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
            StudentRecord w=new StudentRecord("MyName");
            oo.writeObject(w);
```

3.> Reading from the file

```
        File f=new File("xyz.txt");
        fi = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream oi=new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        StudentRecord sr=(StudentRecord)oi.readObject();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was writing File IO to stream instead of my object!

Answer (score 1):

It seems OK. Just make sure that you write / read only Serializable objects which is not clear from your example. Also I would make stream constructions simpler

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStrea(file))
);
```

you don't need to save references to intermediary streams.

Comment: There is a problem, I probably should have included. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to AWorld

I have not used serializable before either and don't know of what you speak. Would you mind explaining please?

Comment: I have tried that, when it runs it says it cannot cast Object to AWorld.

Comment: As I stated, I was writing File IO stream to the file which caused the problem. Sometimes it's the silliest of problems can leave you confused for days.

N.B/ Thank you, I do realise you don't have to reference intermediary streams: It is just so I can understand how it is working (Otherwise I will get even more confused!)